# TFS - Cannot Check-In "big" files

Tags: tfs

I've been working with TFS for months without a problem, now suddently I can't check-in "big" files (2kb files are ok, but 50kb files or multiple files are not). TFS is hosted on a server in the same network.

When I try to check-in, it gives-me an error like: "*Check In: Operation not performed : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
Please refer to the Output window for more information*". The "more information" in output window is just the same error.
The event viewer of the server shows nothing, and I've been looking in Google for the past couple hours and turned out nothing yet.

Comment: First idea: Someone messed with the max request size setting on the TFS web application. Is TFS the only app hosted on that IIS?

Comment: Already checked, "<httpRuntime executionTimeout="3600" maxRequestLength="2097151" />" and no, there's other apps.

Comment: OK, then the general procedure: Go server-side and check what's happening there (IIS logs, traces, etc.). "Underlying connection was closed" is 99% a server side issue. See if you can cut it down to a specific file size (the request will be larger, but if you can nail it down to a certain size, you at least get a ballpark figure of what to look for). Just to remove the client-side possibility: Check same on another client.

Comment: I've checked IIS logs, shows a bunch of POSTs and nothing more. It also happens with another project under the same TFS and with other client. However there's a project that seems to be working; I haven't checked file sizes yet.

Comment: Any chance your server is running out of disk space on the server?

Comment: Nope, there's still 80gb free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message `The underlying connection was closed` is an indicator that something between the client and the server is dropping the connection unexpectedly.

Some things to investigate/try:

1. **Is the application pool on the server restarting**? Look at the Application Event Log on the AT server. Look for ASP.NET and W3SVC warnings/errors that indicate the app pool has restarted.
2. **How is the client connecting to the server**? Is there a HTTP proxy in the middle? Is the server behind a load balancer or firewall device? What is the idle timeout set to? Is it honoring HTTP Keep-Alive settings?
3. **Is it failing for all clients**? Can you checkin the same file on the TFS server itself?

If none of those seem to lead you in the right direction, you'll need to setup a [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/version.asp) or [NetMon](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=983b941d-06cb-4658-b7f6-3088333d062f&displaylang=en) trace on your client and/or your server.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem in TFS 2008, where the lock table was getting big and causing some problems.  Take a look at tbl_lock in your TfsVersionControl database.  This should be a very small number of rows.

In our experience when this number approached or exceeded 1,000 rows, we started seeing significant issues with check-ins.

Our resolution to this was to turn on merging for the binary files that we were storing.

Comment: The table is empty. However I think we've pinpointed the problem. We noticed we could check-in when connecting to the network via cable instead of wireless. The problem is in the network.

Comment: Jorge, you should move your comment to an answer. It was the solution to a problem that had been plaguing me.